# Excel formula for reading a cell and returning currency

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a formula that will read an adjacent cell (in the example, the column "value") and return currency based on either "$", "€", or "£" values appearing.

i.e.

| value | currency |
| --- | --- |
| $10 | US |
| €20 | Euro |
| £20 | Pound |

So far I have =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("$",adjcell)),adjcell,"dollar"), but I am not sure how to add an OR to the end of this formula to duplicate it for euro and pound symbols as well.
How can I do it?

Comment: So the entries containing the currency symbols are formatted as *text*, i.e. the currency symbol physically appears in the cell contents (unlike for a numeric entry which is simply formatted as currency)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The formatting of each cell is text, not currency (each cell is a jumbled mess, with some variation of a currency symbol appearing - most commonly, dollar, euro, and pound).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=LOOKUP(1,0/FIND({"$","€","£"},adjcell),{"Dollar","Euro","Pound"})`